# Multiprocessing with python service

Tags: python, pywin32

I have a windows service created using pywin32. Inside the service I amhave created a plugin based system using yapsy plugin.One of the plugins is deleting videos when disk is low on space.

I am using  python multiprocessing to speed up the process to deleting videos. The setup works fine when tested without service. But when the service is running the _deleteFiles() method is not running. I have made sure the multiprocessing setup is correct and everything is working till i call the method. I am using python 2.7.11 and the forking.py file of multiprocessing seems to be the latest one.

The part of my code which sets up the multiprocessing is shown below.multiprocLib() class is just a wrapper around multiprocessing to make it easier to setup processes and I have used it in many places for successfully.

Am i missing something here? I have tried multprocessing.freeze_support() at many places but none of them have worked.

```
mproc = multiprocLib()
mproc.setNumProcesses(8)
rlock = mproc.RLock()
deleteList = mproc.list()
deleteDict = mproc.dict()
parent, child = mproc.Pipe()
mproc.setTarget(_deleteFiles, (child, deleteList,deleteDict))
mproc.process(parent, videoList, False)


def _deleteFiles(child, deleteList,deleteDict):
# if __debug:
#     fileList = child
# else:
fileList = child.recv()
for file in fileList:
    # if not __debug:
    try:
        os.remove(file)
    except:
        exinfo = sys.exc_info()
        stackTrace = ''.join(traceback.format_tb(exinfo[2]))
        deleteDict[file] = stackTrace
    else:
        deleteList.append(file)
```